# print greys very lightly

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

How can you print grey blocks very very lightly so they're perceptible but not more?

This would be helpful for long forms where part of each page is grey, to save on ink. It is easy to print colours as greyscale, but how can you decrease black ink usage even on greyscale. Obviously draft mode is already enabled.

Solutions involving printing to a pdf and then using acrobat pro to change the greys acceptable, as long as not manually changing every box.

As some of the text is grey, a solution is required which wouldn't print the text light, only the *blocks* of grey.

Comment: You have [pdf] and [adobe-acrobat] tags, and mention the possibility of printing to a pdf, but the actual requirement isn't clear.  Does the document need to end up a pdf, or can it remain the original format?  What software are you using to create the document?  Once it is in pdf format, the darkness of the gray is set, there is no simple way to modify just the gray.  But in the original document, assuming you are using a common program like one of the major office suites, you can make the gray whatever darkness you want.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you save it as, or print it to, a pdf, it will be like however you created it.  The document will appear on screen with the gray whatever darkness you made it.  When it prints, the grey will generally be created from tiny dots of black, and the darkness will be determined by the density of the dots (the percentage of the space filled with dots).  Can you clarify your requirements, and what software you're using?

Comment: It is starting off as a filled in pdf form. I thought that once it is a printed pdf (as opposed to a filled in form) it may be easier to change all the greys. This is a pretty obvious feature for people who want to save ink printing long forms, would have thought possible? Thanks & sorry for not explaining clearly